# DynamoDB - Update item but retain database's current version of a field in that item

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to **Update** one or more fields for an item in **DynamoDB** while keeping the database's current values for others and want to know if this is possible using `context.SaveAsync(item)` or another method in the **AWS SDK for .NET** or if I have to read the entry from the database first, apply those changes, and then perform the save (which is still prone to issues).

The reason for this being, is that I have a *counter* that goes up from other user's modifying the item, but the owner of the item wishes to change other fields. The owner may not have the most recent version of this entry (due to other users modifying that counter since the time the owner retrieved it) so I want to save the owner's edits but retain the Database's instance of the *counter*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform updates to DynamoDB columns using [UpdateItemAsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) method.

Use UpdateExpression, ConditionExpression and ExpressionAttributeNames, ExpressionAttributeValues in [UpdateItemRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_Model_UpdateItemRequest.htm) to configure your updates.

```
                var updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest
            {
                TableName = "DDBTableName",
                Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                {
                    {"key_name", new AttributeValue { S = "Value"} }
                },
                ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "#C", "ColumnName" } },
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                {
                    {":unlock", new AttributeValue{ BOOL= false }},
                    {":lock", new AttributeValue{ BOOL = true }}
                },
                ConditionExpression = "attribute_exists(ColumnName) AND #C = :lock",
                UpdateExpression = "SET #C = :unlock",
                ReturnValues = ReturnValue.ALL_NEW
            };

          var  updatedItemResponse = await dynamoDBClient.UpdateItemAsync(updateItemRequest);
```